# GeoMesa Plugin (WFS/WMS/WPS) Build Failure

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, wms, geomesa

I am building Geomesa using maven and encountered the errors below. The whole build is fine except for the Geomesa Plug-in for geoserver which will support WMS/WFS services.

```
[ERROR] error: error while loading <root>, error in opening zip file 
[ERROR] error: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found. 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:48) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:40) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:61) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getPackage(Mirrors.scala:172) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredPackage(Mirrors.scala:175) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackage$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:183) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackage(Definitions.scala:183) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackageClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:184) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackageClass(Definitions.scala:184) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnnotationDefaultAttr$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1024) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnnotationDefaultAttr(Definitions.scala:1023) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1153) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses(Definitions.scala:1152) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1196) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode(Definitions.scala:1196) 
[ERROR]     at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1261) 
[ERROR]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1290) 
[ERROR]     at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:32) 
[ERROR]     at scala.tools.nsc.Main$.doCompile(Main.scala:79) 
[ERROR]     at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:54) 
[ERROR]     at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.main(Driver.scala:67) 
[ERROR]     at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala) 
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
[ERROR]     at scala_maven_executions.MainHelper.runMain(MainHelper.java:164) 
[ERROR]     at scala_maven_executions.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:26) 
[ERROR]
```

### [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

### Summary of build

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary: 
[INFO] 
[INFO] GeoMesa - [Accumulo 1.5.x] ........................ SUCCESS [9.033s] 
[INFO] GeoMesa Utils - [Accumulo 1.5.x] .................. SUCCESS [4:28.300s] 
[INFO] GeoMesa Filters and Functions - [Accumulo 1.5.x] .. SUCCESS [22.596s] 
[INFO] GeoMesa Avro SimpleFeature - [Accumulo 1.5.x] ..... SUCCESS [2:51.698s] 
[INFO] GeoMesa Core - [Accumulo 1.5.x] ................... SUCCESS [33:01.644s] 
[INFO] GeoMesa Distributed Runtime - [Accumulo 1.5.x] .... SUCCESS [1:34.394s] 
[INFO] GeoMesa Plugin (WFS/WMS/WPS) - [Accumulo 1.5.x] ... FAILURE [5:56.617s] 
[INFO] GeoMesa Distribution tar.gz - [Accumulo 1.5.x] .... SKIPPED 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 48:26.897s 
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jul 14 18:56:13 IST 2014 
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/165M 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.1.0:compile (scala-compile-first) on project geomesa-plugin-accumulo1.5: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Query resolved.
The error was in asm files in maven repository.I just downloaded the asm-3.1.jar and asm-3.1.pom files from maven repository and replaced those in my local maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

The error was in asm files in maven repository.Please download the asm-3.1.jar and asm-3.1.pom files from maven repository and replaced those